# Javascript. Backup and restore object

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using Knockout and jQuery. I need to implement "cancel button behavior" for jquery ui dialog. Dialog contains form with knockout bindings.

How can I backup my object and restore it's state if user cancelled changes?

UPDATE: I need to restore not just field data but **everything**

Comment: i guess you are looking for local storage !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Simple Editor Pattern for Knockout.js](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/01/simple-editor-pattern-knockout-js.html)

It contains a proper way to implement edit/save/cancel actions.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to clone the object when needed.

```
 var cloned = jQuery.extend({}, myObject);
```

and then restore it

```
 myObject = cloned ;
```

Comment: Thought about it. I'll check wether it help

Answer (score 1):

Is that you means Clone Object ?

If you are, you can use the [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/)

```
var backup = $.extend({},before)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as others suggest to clone your view model. But use the clone inside the modal, then persist the data back afterwards.